# Ping Services for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm creating MVC application and would like to add options to use ping services. Does anyone done it before or know the working example? how to integrate that kind of module with asp.net application. and how it works in general?

**Thank you in advance for helpful examples and explanation**

Comment: Ping, as in to see if the site is up and functional?

Comment: And if web master is smart, he would disable ping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://madskristensen.net/post/Ping-using-XML-RPC-in-ASPNET.aspx - should work for your scenario. Let me know if it works becasue I didn't try to implement it.